# Google Chrome indicator icons missing in 17.10

Tags: google-chrome, indicator, ubuntu-gnome

In Ubuntu 17.10 Google Chrome indicator icons are missing. In the previous versions of Ubuntu, Google Chrome was adding a main icon form where it was possible to completely terminate its processes, plus the Extension icons (eg. Hangouts icon):
[image: screenshot of 17.04]

After the update to 17.10 some indicator icons are shown (eg. Steam, InSync and Dropbox) but the one from Chrome are missing:
[image: screenshot of missing icons]

Comment: Try using TopIcons Plus extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind but for now I would like to find a solution that doesn't require any additional extension.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find another solution than adding the extension Topicon Plus.

GNOME got rid of its notification panel in 3.26. Ubuntu added an extension to manage that. But it's not as feature complete as Topicon Plus.

Comment: I dont' get why it works for some apps (e.g. Steam and Dropbox) but not for Chrome. This seems more like a bug than a missing feature.

Answer (score 1):

Either use [TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) or [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) extension. Both works in Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in Chrome 66.0.3359.33.

**Old answer**
I found a temporary workaround: forcing `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` for Chrome.

In Ubuntu 17.10 `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` has changed to `ubuntu:GNOME` and this seems to not be correctly handled by Chromium/Chrome (bug report [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=797332&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=indicator&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=)).

Starting Chromium/Chrome with `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` seems to temporarily fix the issue.

To make it permanent I just modified my Chrome launcher to always start it with that value:

`env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity /usr/bin/google-chrome-beta %U`